# Jquery, require.js, backbone.js. sample application

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

What is the use of a module loader? How it can be use in JQuery?
 How to use require.js as module loader.
Please share the sample application too. if you have!!

Comment: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/ check this tutorial out, it's a bit old, but still a good primer. Then check out this https://github.com/jcreamer898/RequireJS-Backbone-Starter/ it incorporates some of the newer features of require.js that the first  tutorial doesn't cover (mainly shims).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I go in parts

**What is a module loader?**

OK In Js you can't use a import instruction (well yes in node you can.) so many people stick their code all together (even the librarys their using) so they don't have to load anything, but this can bring large js files and add load time to your app, other people think that they separate the code and use the  tag to load by pieces but this is unpractical as you have to maintain all definitions in the html pages, so here is were require.js comes and help you to [decopule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling#Software_development) your code by creating modules and load then on demand. this make easy to separate your code and have small pieces easier to fix, maintain or add features.

from require.js docs

"When a project reaches a certain size, managing the script modules for a project starts to get tricky. You need to be sure to sequence the scripts in the right order, and you need to start seriously thinking about combining scripts together into a bundle for deployment, so that only one or a very small number of requests are made to load the scripts."

**How it can be use in JQuery?**

I will change the question to **How it can be use with JQuery**?

You will load Jquery as an dependency when is need it you have a basic example [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#setup)

**How to use require.js as module loader?**

here a little snippet of code

the html need it

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
          <title>jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</title>
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require-jquery.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</h1>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Our main.js

```
require(["jquery", "jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta"], function($) {
    //the jquery.alpha.js and jquery.beta.js plugins have been loaded.
    $(function() {
        $('body').alpha().beta();
    });
});
```

part of the config

```
paths: {
        "jquery": "require-jquery"
    },

    modules: [
        {
            name: "main",
            exclude: ["jquery"]
        }
```

I hope this can help you. You can download an example project [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/release/jquery-require/jquery1.7.2-requirejs2.0.4/jquery-require-sample.zip)

I will add an example of my app so you can see how use Backbone and require

the config

```
require.config({
    shim: {
      'underscore': {
        deps: ['jquery'], //dependencies
        exports: '_' //the exported symbol
      },
      backbone: {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
      }
    }

    paths: {
      jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min',
      underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
      backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',

    }

  });
```

An example module

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
    //Your code Here
  });
```

Have fun working with require :-)